# How to change the font size and color of x-axis and y-axis label in a scatterplot with plot function in R?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I used the following code to draw a scatterplot. How to increase the font size and change colour of x-axis and y-axis label?

```
data=read.csv("data.csv") 
plot(data$column1,data$column2,xlab="x axis", ylab="y axis",  pch=19)
```

Comment: Have a look at `?par`, especially `col.axis` and `cex.axis`

Comment: @rebca: I have more than enough points. I hope you switch the check to mnel's post.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To track down the correct parameters you need to go first to `?plot.default`, which refers you to `?par` and `?axis`:

```
plot(1, 1 ,xlab="x axis", ylab="y axis",  pch=19,
           col.lab="red", cex.lab=1.5,    #  for the xlab and ylab
           col="green")                   #  for the points
```

Comment: @Dwin Thank you for your answer.How can I change the color of  dots on the scatterplot?

Comment: The 'col' parameter should change the color of the plotted points.

Answer (score 57):

Look at `?par` for the various graphics parameters.

In general `cex` controls size, `col` controls colour. If you want to control the colour of a label, the `par` is `col.lab`, the colour of the axis annotations `col.axis`, the colour of the `main` text, `col.main` etc. The names are quite intuitive, once you know where to begin.

For example

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10

plot(x , y,xlab="x axis", ylab="y axis",  pch=19, col.axis = 'blue', col.lab = 'red', cex.axis = 1.5, cex.lab = 2)
```

[image]

If you need to change the colour / style of the surrounding box and axis lines, then look at `?axis` or `?box`, and you will find that you will be using the same parameter names within calls to `box`  and axis.

You have a lot of control to make things however you wish.

eg

```
plot(x , y,xlab="x axis", ylab="y axis",  pch=19,  cex.lab = 2, axes = F,col.lab = 'red')
box(col = 'lightblue')
axis(1, col = 'blue', col.axis = 'purple', col.ticks = 'darkred', cex.axis = 1.5, font = 2, family = 'serif')
axis(2, col = 'maroon', col.axis = 'pink', col.ticks = 'limegreen', cex.axis = 0.9, font =3, family = 'mono')
```

[image]

Which is seriously ugly, but shows part of what you can control

Answer (score 1):

Taking DWins example.

What I often do, particularly when I use many, many different plots with the same colours or
size information, is I store them in variables I otherwise never use.
This helps me keep my code a little cleaner AND I can change it "globally".

E.g.

```
clab = 1.5
cmain = 2
caxis = 1.2

plot(1, 1 ,xlab="x axis", ylab="y axis",  pch=19,
           col.lab="red", cex.lab=clab,    
           col="green", main = "Testing scatterplots", cex.main =cmain, cex.axis=caxis)
```

You can also write a function, doing something similar. But for a quick shot this is ideal.
You can also store that kind of information in an extra script, so you don't have a messy plot script:

which you then call with
setwd("")
source("plotcolours.r")

in a file say called plotcolours.r you then store all the e.g. colour or size variables

```
clab = 1.5
cmain = 2
caxis = 1.2
```

for colours could use

```
darkred<-rgb(113,28,47,maxColorValue=255)
```

as your variable 'darkred' now has the colour information stored, you can access it in your actual plotting script.

```
plot(1,1,col=darkred)
```

Comment: Seems like you could easily confuse `col=darkred` with `col="darkred"`